# asp.net MVC default action not working in area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a project with a setup area declared and a URL that works as long as I explicitly include the "/Index" action. The problem is when I use RedirectToAction("Index") it excludes "/Index" from the URL and I get a 404 Page Not Found. The URLs are:

`http://localhost:40078/Setup/Facility/Index` - Works
`http://localhost:40078/Setup/Facility/` - 404 (with or without trailing /)

RouteConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "T.C.MVCWeb.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

SetupAreaRegistration:

```
public class SetupAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Setup";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Setup_default",
            "Setup/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "T.C.MVCWeb.Areas.Setup.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Requested Controller

```
namespace T.C.MVCWeb.Areas.Setup.Controllers
{
    public class FacilityController : Controller
    {
        // GET: FacilitySetup
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I added Phil Haack's RouteDebugger and can see that the 404 request thinks "Setup" is the controller, but I don't understand why and the rest of the output is confusing me more than it's helping.

Comment: Most likely there is an attribute route that is registered *before* your area route that is matching `/Setup/Facility/`. That could be an attribute route or another area route in your config. Does it match if you comment out `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` as a test?

Comment: Good call, you're right. One of my developers has a ton of attribute routes set up for some reason. The offending one was `Setup/{action}` which was intended to allow the area URL itself `http://localhost:40078/Setup/` to map to a `SetupController`. I think the only option is to hardcode a route for each action there, right? E.G. `Setup/Index` that defaults to the `Setup` controller and `Index` action? After doing that both URLs work. What threw me off is RouteDebugger doesn't highlight `Setup/{action}` as matching my Facility URL. It only shows "n/a" as a match at the top of the list. Thanks!

Comment: Either use URLs with constant segments, or a route constraint to ensure they don't match the routes you intend for the `\Setup` area. Although, it seems your main issue is having 2 different sections of the site named `Setup` - it might be more maintainable to move all of that into the `Setup` area.

Comment: There aren't 2 different sections. `SetupController` is in the `Setup` area. We just want the URL for the area itself to host a landing page for the area. I guess that could just be specified as `Setup_default`'s default controller and action, but he was trying to allow it to have a dynamic `{action}` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NightOwn888's comment, I found a route declared via an attribute. The offending route attribute declared Setup/{action} which was intended to allow the area URL itself http://localhost:40078/Setup/ to map to a SetupController.